# Kafka producer hangs if topic doesn't exist

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to Kafka and trying to implement a simple producer, sending data to a topic.
If the topic doesn't exist, I want to handle the sutiation as an exception.

```
private Producer<UUID, Object> producer = createProducer(); 

private static Producer createProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "mybootstrapserveraddress");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "ADAPTER");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            UUIDSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            JsonSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,
            1000);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,
            1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG,
            1000);
    return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
}

public void send(Event event, String topic){
    try {
        UUID key = UUID.randomUUID();
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key , event), (rm, ex) -> {
            if (ex != null) {
                log.warn("Error sending message with key {}\n{}", new Object[]{key, ex.getMessage()});
            } else {
                log.info( "Partition for key-value {} is {}", new Object[]{key, rm.partition()});
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to send message ",e);
    } finally {
        producer.flush();
    }
}
```

However, if the topic doesn't exist, the message continues to be polled. Timeouts and retries from ProducerConfig are ignored.

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | ADAPTER] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=ADAPTER] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {my-example-topic2=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
[kafka-producer-network-thread | ADAPTER] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=ADAPTER] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 7 : {my-example-topic2=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
[kafka-producer-network-thread | ADAPTER] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=ADAPTER] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 8 : {my-example-topic2=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

I do not want to check that the topic exist through AdminClient.
Kafka document https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs was of no help.

Is there a way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the topic doesn't exist the retry for getting metadata should ends after 60 seconds by default raising a timeout exception at the end.
The producer config parameter related to that is `max.block.ms` (default 60000).
As far as I know, there is no way to have feedback earlier than reducing this timeout or using the AdminClient (which is something you don't want to do).

Comment: Do you have any insights if this is still in place? Im having the exact same problem here, but setting max.block.ms doesnt have any effect here.

Comment: @glace I also set request.timeout.ms and retries = 1 as well

Answer (score 1):

Kafka will throw a `MetadataNotUpdated` exception if there is any trouble publishing a message (it blocks on the `send` method). The timeout is configurable using: `max.block.ms`. However, make sure that auto topic creation is not disabled.

Comment: Actually, it's org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException, not MetadataNotUpdated exception.

Comment: Damn sorry my mistake. You're correct. Long time since I saw this exception.